# Possible to attach a wrist strap to a "naked" GoPro Hero8?

Tags: gopro, camera-straps

My son has a GoPro Hero 8. He's enjoying taking videos whilst walking outside. I'm worried about him dropping it. He doesn't yet have a case - we're hoping the "[Rollcage](https://gopro.com/en/us/shop/mounts-accessories/rollcage/AJFRC-001.html)" case will suit his needs nicely, but it isn't out yet.

I'd be a little more comfortable if he could carry the camera with a strap like the one below, loosely around his wrist.

[image: A tether cord I'm hoping to attach to the GoPro]

I'm wondering if we could attach this to the "naked" camera. There are two promising looking holes - see my picture below. But! The manual doesn't seem to explain what these holes are for, and I'm a bit wary of trying, in case they turn out to be eg microphone drainage holes.

[image: GoPro Hero8 from below, with holes highlighted]

Are these holes appropriate for attaching a wrist strap? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 5):

> Are these holes appropriate for attaching a wrist strap?

No. Those holes are for the bottom and side microphones. They are not meant to mount a strap to.

> Or is there another way?

Sure. You can use one of the built-in folding mount fingers bosses on the bottom. Just fold one or both of the fingers down to loop the strap through the hole with a simple [cow hitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cow_hitch).

Comment: It's called a girth hitch. What 'r you, a cowboy? ;-) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FhFmIKxW4lw

Comment: @hueco Lol. I tend to see it referred to most often a lark's head knot in hammock-hanging circles. Which I find interesting, because I figure there's quite a bit of overlap between climbers and backcountry campers.

Comment: There is a bit of overlap but while most climbers are campers, not all campers are climbers. I've had a few naming conversations with sailors as well back when I was climbing-guiding. It's interesting that so many communities have so many names for the same hitches and knots...as if they all discovered them independently from one another.

Comment: @Hueco 100% same observation here. The clmber->camper correlation is much higher than camper->climber. My grandpa (WWII US Navy) taught me most of my knots, and the rest I know from Ashleigh Book of Knots, etc. I find it really interesting that different fields have different names for many knots, but ones such as bowline (and derivatives such as bowline-in-the-bight, etc.) are pretty universal, and nautical in persistent nomenclature. Tangentially, I've found the most useful general purpose knot to be an alpine butterfly knot. Definitely a climber knot, but so useful in so many other areas.

Comment: I find the clove hitch to be useful in day to day as well, especially for impromptu leashing my dog to whatever sturdy object is nearby. Alpine bends were big when I was learning to climb...that summer had a few rappel deaths so the need to not cut corners on rap was an idea that got pretty much burned into me.

Comment: @Hueco just to be clear, I meant the alpine as a climber knot in name only (that is, it's universally known that way; I've never seen it with another name). but while I've thought of it as a good utility knot (load lashing, mid-span loop, etc.), I've always been suspect of it for safety critical purposes. More a knot of convenience, rather than a go-to knot when you have plenty of time to do fig-8 followthroughs, etc. (Disclaimer: my climbing experience is very rudimentary, almost all top roping short sport routes)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103693/discussion-between-hueco-and-scottbb).